# Which shell am I running on?

Tags: bash, tcsh

When I run `echo $SHELL` the output says `/bin/tcsh` which means that I am running a `tcsh` shell.
But for example when I issue the following command

```
alias emacs 'emacs -nw'
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: alias: emacs: not found
bash: alias: emacs -nw: not found
```

and when I issue `alias emacs="emacs -nw"` it runs fine!

This is confusing since I am running `tcsh` but the commands are interpreted by `bash`.

What could be the reason?

Comment: `tcsh/csh` has its current shell in `$shell`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`$SHELL` is not necessarily your current shell, it is the [default login shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#SHELLVARREF). To check the shell you are using, try

```
ps $$
```

This should work on most recent Unix/Linux with a `ps` that supports the BSD syntax. Otherwise, this is the portable (POSIX) way

```
ps -p $$
```

That should return something like this if you are running `tcsh`:

```
8773 pts/10   00:00:00 tcsh
```

If you want to have `tcsh` be your default shell, use `chsh` to set it.

Comment: Do you know how can I check that which config file is loaded? (which bashrc)

Comment: @Coffe_Mug not sure what you mean. You can set the default shell with `chsh`, `.bashrc` will only be read if you are i) running bash and ii) running it as an interactive, non-login shell. How are you logging into this machine?

Comment: I have a script which starts this bash shell from a tcsh shell.

Comment: @Coffe_Mug OK, so what are you asking? Ping me (@terdon) on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) if you have more questions.

Comment: Why not just `ps $$`

Comment: @cjm why not indeed, answer edited.

Comment: Strictly, it's your **default shell for this process**, as it's just an ordinary environment variable that can be changed.  It's quite reasonable to have different values in different processes.  It just happens to be set for you at login.

Comment: @cjm `ps $$` is non portable BSDism and won't work at least with Solaris 10 and older standard `ps`. POSIX requires the process list to be introduced by the `-p` option.

Comment: in `csh/tcsh`, `echo $shell` tells the current shell.

Comment: @HongboZhu `$shell` is not the same as `$SHELL`. The `$shell` variable seems to be some sort of internal tcsh thing, but `$SHELL` is an environment variable and only holds the user's default login shell. Still, that's a useful suggestion for the case of csh/tcsh, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

From the command line, you can also use the `$0` variable to determine which shell you are using.  e.g.:

```
~$ echo $0
/bin/bash


~$ ksh
$ echo $0
ksh
```

Note: you cannot determine the shell using $0 within a script, because $0 will be the script itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is an amendment to all of the better answers above. I had a tiny issue identifying dash at one point; seemed right to share:

```
curl -fsSL http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/whatshell.sh | sh
ash (dash 0.5.5.1 ff)

curl -fsSL http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/whatshell.sh | bash
bash 4.3.30(1)-release
```

Good for troubleshooting in tight spots is all. Cheers.

Comment: So it's using curl to download that script, and then it passes it to the shell you indicate after the pipe, and the script is such that by the way it is processed it is possible to understand what shell it is?

Comment: yeah, seems like you would already know which shell you're using but in the case you inherited a system with `sh` that could be Bourne shell, `ash` (Almquist shell) or `dash` (Debian Almquist shell) - and they all behave slightly different. UNIX was all over the place though; that was the whole reason for GNU. Bash is pretty much jut Bash; this will tell you a version but you can get that the normal way, `bash --version` or `echo $BASH_VERSION`. I just like how this script is a one-stop-shop for everything.

Answer (score 1):

This works for linux:

```
lsof -a -p $$ -d txt
```

or, if you need a stronger selection (more systems):

```
lsof -a +D /bin +D /usr/bin -p $$ -d txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A Unix/Linux Operating System may have more than one shell installed.
You can type the following command in your terminal to see which shell you are using:

Below is the list,

- Bourne Shell – sh
- C Shell – csh
- T Shell – tcsh
- Korn Shell – ksh
- Bourn-again Shell – bash
- Dash Shell
- Z shell

This list is not complete and there are many other shells.

/etc/shells file stores list of all shells installed in your system. Simply, run the below command to find out the installed shells,

```
$ cat /etc/shells
```

Run grep command on /etc/passwd file to know the default shell when you log in to Unix or Linux operating system.

```
$ grep john /etc/passwd
```

You can also use the $SHELL variable for the same purpose.

```
echo $0
$ echo $SHELL
```

The result will look something similar to the below if you are using the *bash* (**Bourne Again Shell**) terminal:
When there are multiple shells installed on your system, you can always switch the shell.

so how do you know which shell you are running at the moment?

Simply use the below command

```
-bash
$ ps -p $$
```

I think all your questions are answered. If you still have a doubt, you can refer to [this source article](https://www.imaginelinux.com/which-unix-shell/).