# Why isn't ~/.bash_profile executed when starting Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu in Virtualbox in a MacBook Pro laptop.
In `~/.bash_profile`, I added some directories to `PATH`. But after I reboot the guest Ubuntu, the added directories are not in `PATH`. I wonder why `~/.bash_profile` isn't executed after the guest Ubuntu starts. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're running bash? `/bin/sh` links to `dash` in recent Ubuntu.

Comment: Right. It links to dash, which I didn't know. (1) Shall I put the change to `PATH` in `~/.profile`? (2) How does one find out what the current running shell is, e.g. bash, dash, zsh?

Comment: (1) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path  (2) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96305/which-shell-i-am-running-on

Answer (score 3):

You should put your environment variables in `~/.profile`.

> In this file you can also place environment variable assignments,
>   since it gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the
>   start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when
>   one logs in from the textual console.

— https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4-.2F.profile