# Xvfb: export display permanently

Tags: x11, display, xvfb, display-server

I have recently set up Xvfb on Centos 7 machine.

It is working absolutely fine.

Only problem is that if I quit putty session (remote access) it would keep running Xvfb in background but display will be gone.

So next time when I take remote access via putty first I have to type `export DISPLAY=:99` again, then I start my tests.

How can I make it permanent? I don't see solution to my problem in this thread [How to make exported shell variables permanent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/how-to-make-exported-shell-variables-permanent)

**Update:**
.profile contents:

```
export M3_HOME=/home/aditi.a/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M3_HOME

export JMETER_HOME=/home/aditi.a/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JMETER_HOME

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_192-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export DISPLAY=:99
```

**echo variables output:**

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_192-amd64
$ echo $M3_HOME
/home/adit.a/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin
$ echo $DISPLAY

$
```

*which shell I am running*

```
$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
30678 pts/14   00:00:00 sh
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  Which of the answers from the linked question have you tried?

Comment: I have added this line `export DISPLAY=:99` in `.profile` file where JAVA, MAVEN environment variables are saved. Quit putty session and ran the tests, tests failed because display wasnt there, exported the display again and test run fine this time

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Some shells will only read `~/.profile` as a fallback, if some other startup file isn't present.

Comment: Do you mean in order to get permanently running the display this is the correct way?. To answer question, I am sure that it is the correct .profile file because it is reading Maven, Jmeter, Java from there perfectly.

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/478625/edit) to show the contents of your `.profile`, and confirm that the other variables set there *do* take effect (when you connect through putty/ssh)?

Comment: @JigglyNaga done.

Comment: I also asked you to confirm that the other variables in there *are* set as expected:  When you've connected via putty, and you type `echo $JAVA_HOME`, or `echo $M3_HOME`, or `echo $DISPLAY`, what is the result?

Comment: added, please check. It is black for $DISPLAY

Comment: And which shell are you using?  (See [Which shell am I running on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96305/which-shell-am-i-running-on) if you're not sure.)  If it's `bash`, do either `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` exist?

Comment: added output of  `ps -p $$`

Comment: That all looks like it should work.  When the shell reads that `.profile`, it will set `DISPLAY` along with the other variables.  When I recreate the exact steps you've described (Centos 7, shell=`/usr/bin/sh`, set `DISPLAY` in `~/.profile`, connect via Putty), `DISPLAY` is set.  So there must be something else non-standard about your setup, or a missing step you've not mentioned.  If your problem can't be reproduced by anyone else, there's no way to investigate, and a "fix" won't be useful to anyone else.

Comment: You might try adding more `echo display=$DISPLAY` lines at the start and end of `.profile` to see whether `.profile` isn't being (fully) used, or something else is unsetting the variable afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second what @JigglyNaga said, there is nothing wrong/missing after looking at your `.profile` file.

Only thing I would suggest copy same contents at

`/home/aditi.a/.profile` and `.bashrc` 
`/root/.profile` and `.bashrc` files

Comment: This worked. I quit putty launched again and ran tests, it run fine this time.